# Convert string to date from an excel file asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

After putting this code and importing excel file, I'm always encountering data tables with no values even though most of the rows has values in the excel file. My problem is to convert string (ex. 20131022) to date (yyyyMMdd) after importing excel file and show "N/A" as the value if it is null or 0.

Here's my code:

//AdminController.cs

```
if (data.ordDate == "0" || data.ordDate == null)
{
Response.Write("N/A");
}
else
{
data.ordDate = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ordDate"].ToString();
}

if (data.paymentDate == "0" || data.paymentDate == null)
{
Response.Write("N/A");
}
else
{
data.paymentDate = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["paymentDate"].ToString();
}
```

//ExcelData.cs

```
public class ExcelData
    {
        public string ordDate { get; set; } 
        public string paymentDate { get; set; }
    }
```

//_ExcelData.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<ExcelData>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Order Date</th>
            <th>Payment Date</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @try
        {
            foreach (var data in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>@data.ordDate</td>
                <td>@data.paymentDate</td>           
            </tr>
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5">No data available.</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Can you help me guys with this?
My whole day is so f***** up with this code. I'm new in ASP.NET MVC. I tried the other format but still it shows nothing except for the row of 
N/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/AN/A
on the top of the data table.

Thanks in advance to those who are willing to help! :)

Comment: Hi Damith, here: ExcelData data = new ExcelData(); I also edited my post. Please check again. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could create a method to deal with it:

```
public static string ConvertDateTime(string data)
{
    DateTime dateTime;
    return DateTime.TryParseExact(data
        , "yyyyMMdd"
        , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime) 
        ? dateTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd") : "N/A";
}
```

or without format checking:

```
public static string ConvertDateTime(string data)
{
    return data == "0" || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data) ? "N/A" : data;
}
```

and your main method(AdminController.cs) can use it to get the datetime value:

```
data.ordDate = ConvertDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ordDate"].ToString());
data.paymentDate = ConvertDateTime(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["paymentDate "].ToString());
```

Comment: Hi, where will I put this,
{
DateTime dateTime;
    return DateTime.TryParseExact(data
        , "yyyyMMdd"
        , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime) 
        ? dateTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd") : "N/A";
}

ExcelData.cs? AdminController.cs? _ExcelData.cshtml?

Comment: In AdminController.cs is ok, and if there are another methods will use the method, you may consider to put it on a globally shared tool class.

Comment: I encountered this after using your codes:

Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


The current request for action 'OrderExcelData' on controller type 'AdminController' is ambiguous between the following action methods:
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult OrderExcelData() on type crmc.Controllers.AdminController
System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult OrderExcelData(System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase) on type crmc.Controllers.AdminController

Comment: That's because you defined two same name actions in one controller.The action requesting does not support method overloading.you may rename them to different names or define them different request methods:"HttpPost" and "HttpGet".

Comment: Oh, okay. :) I used it already but the ordDate and paymentDate shows N/A in all rows. Most of it has values. @Chris

Comment: I think maybe you could post some source data within ordDate and paymentDate, so I could find out why it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi, is this what you need? (:

ordDate   paymentDate
20130606 
0 0 
0 20130528
0 20130528

Comment: no, I mean the value of "ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ordDate"].ToString()", maybe the format is incorrect for "yyyyMMdd" or there are blanks at the start or end of the string.

Comment: Hi. The value of "ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ordDate"].ToString()" is 20130606

Comment: Then You may try the other method I've edited to the answer. Oh.. the problem would be solved in 5 minutes if I could debug your code directly:)

Comment: Hi Chris! The without format checking works! But this is not converted to date. Anyway, thank you so much for helping me! :)

Comment: If the second method works but the first not, I think there must something wrong with your string format. I'm sorry for taking so long time and not solve your problem:(

Comment: Oh, it's ok Chris. I appreciate all your efforts in helping me, anyway, can I give 1 reputation even if I'm new here? Coz I'd like to give you one :)

Comment: oh,thank you,but you couldn't give, and you do not have to, it's OK. keep it to anyone else who do solve your problems:)

Comment: Hi @Chris! The first method works just like the second! :) I think restarting my computer helps showing the values and N/A, too. :)) (just an update ^_^)

Comment: Yup. I also edited your method and it works! Thanks again @Chris! :)